# How do I deselect all checkboxes in Flex 4

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, checkbox, flex4, flex4.6

I am trying to deselect all checkboxes on a button click.  I've tried creating a binded boolean variable like this:

```
[Bindable]
public var allselected:Boolean;
```

and then on my checkboxes:

```
<s:CheckBox selected="{allselected}" label="PT Identified" />
<s:CheckBox selected="{allselected}" label="Chart Reviewed"/>
<s:CheckBox selected="{allselected}" label="H&amp;P"/>
<s:CheckBox selected="{allselected}" label="Permit Signed"/>
```

On a separate button click I set the boolean variable to false and nothing happens after I've already checked a checkbox.  If I set the boolean variable to true, all the checkboxes get checked.  So, if I wanted to select all, then it works.  However, I want to deselect all selected checkboxes.

The checkboxes only reside withing a tilegroup and are not inside a datagrid or datagroup.  I would think that there is a simple way to do this but I've yet to figure it out.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function findChild(numChilds:int, parent:Object):void
        {
            for (var i:int = 0; i < numChilds; i++)
            {
                var obj:Object = parent.getChildAt(i);
                if(obj.hasOwnProperty('selected'))
                {
                    if(obj.selected == true)
                    {
                        obj.selected = false;
                    }
                }
                if (obj is DisplayObjectContainer)
                {
                    // search for children
                    var children:int = obj.numChildren;
                    findChild(children, obj);
                }
            }
        }
```

Usage:

```
var elems:int = checklistVgroup.numChildren;  // Get the number of elements

findChild(elems, checklistVgroup);            // Use our function
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a dirty solution. Give ids to checkboxes and use the following function for Button click:

```
protected function untick_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void{
            cb1.selected=false;
            cb2.selected=false;
            cb3.selected=false;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks but there are too many checkboxes.  I figured out a solution: